# Код работает, но на stepik.org выдает "Failed test #9 of 37. Cannot check answer. Perhaps output format is wrong."

Tags: python

```
a = float(input())
b = float(input())
op = str(input())
if op == '+':
    print(a + b)
elif op == '-':
    print(a - b)
elif op == '/' and b != 0:
    print(a / b)
elif op == '*':
    print(a * b)
elif op == 'mod' and b != 0:
    print(a % b)
elif op == 'pow':
    print(a ** b)
elif op == 'div' and b != 0:
    print(a // b)
if b == 0 and (op == '/' or 'mod' or 'div'):
    print('Деление на 0!')
```

Comment: Трудно ответить на вопрос без описания задания. Возможно, тест ожидает int, а получает float. Возможно, при делении на ноль ожидает другой ответ.

Comment: Ой, не добавил ссылку, исправляюсь: https://stepik.org/lesson/5047/step/3?unit=1086

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот такая строка `op == '/' or 'mod' or 'div'` будет всегда верна.
Вам надо сравнить `op == '/' or op == 'mod' or op == 'div'`
Или же есть вариант: `op in ('/', 'mod', 'div')`

```py
bool(False or "mod") #true 
my_var = False or "mod" #my_var == "mod"
my_var = True or "mod" #my_var == True
```

Comment: 2й вариант сработал, спасибо!